# How to send post param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having some trouble getting my controller to read the value in my taxable param. I think it may be this `if params[:taxable] == "0"`, but I have tried a ton of different combinations with no luck.

order form

```
<%= f.input :taxable, :as => :boolean %>
```

order controller

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(
    :taxable => params[:order][:taxable],
  )

  if params[:taxable] == "0"
    @order.tax = 0
  else
    @order.tax = (get_tax_for_order(@order))
  end

end
```

order model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :taxable

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:taxable)
  end
```

Comment: What does your `form_for` look like?

Comment: `<%= simple_form_for([@campaign, @order], :html => { :id => "checkout", :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>`  I can see the correct value in console after the form is submit, so I think I am trying to access it incorrectly in the controller

Comment: Try changing the line `if params[:taxable] == "0"` to `if params[:order][:taxable] == "0"` And also what is `tax` in `@order.tax = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said,this line

```
if params[:taxable] == "0"
```

should be

```
if params[:order][:taxable] == "0"
```

As the `taxable` is within the `order` hash.